# Input validation on search (Showing "no search result" on empty input)

Tags: php, mysql, search

hi im working on a search program using php. below is my codes. its running but when i just click the search button it still print an output. what i want is if i will click the button search without imputing something on its text  it will print the message"$output = 'there was no search result'". how will i do that? thanks in advance...

```
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search...">
<input type= 'submit' name= 'btnsearch' value= 'search' id= 'btnsearch' onclick=         'this.form.action'/>
<input type = 'submit' name = 'download' value = 'save to excel'/>


<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("could not connect");
mysql_select_db("copylandia") or die ("could not find db");


$output = '';
if(isset($_POST['btnsearch']))
{
$searchq = $_POST['search'];
/*$searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);*/

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE initial LIKE '%$searchq%' OR lname             LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die ("could not search");
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);

if($count == FALSE)

{

$output = 'There was no search results!';

}
else
{ 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$id = $row['number'];
$Initials = $row['initial'];
$name = $row['fname'];
$lastname = $row['lname'];
$middle = $row['mname'];
$email = $row['emailadd'];
$uname = $row['username'];
$pass = $row['password'];
$Group = $row['group'];
$Position = $row['position'];
$Level1 = $row['level1'];
$Level2 = $row['level2'];
$Level3 = $row['level3'];
$Level4 = $row['level4'];
$Level5 = $row['level5'];
$Level6 = $row['level6'];
$Level7 = $row['level7'];

$output .= 'Initial : '.$Initials.'<br> 
First Name : '.$name.'<br> 
Last Name : '.$lastname.' <br> 
Middle Name : '.$middle.' <br> 
Email Add : '.$email.'<br> 
Username : '.$uname.'<br> 
Password : '.$pass.'<br> 
Group : '.$Group.'<br> 
Position : '.$Position.'<br> 
Level 1 : '.$Level1.'<br> 
Level 2 : '.$Level2.'<br> 
Level 3 : '.$Level3.'<br> 
Level 4 : '.$Level4.'<br> 
Level 5 : '.$Level5.'<br> 
Level 6 : '.$Level6.'<br> 
Level 7 : '.$Level7.'<br>
-------------------------------------<br>';

}

}

print "$output";
}
?>

<?php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this

```
    if(isset($_POST['btnsearch']))
    {
    $searchq = $_POST['search'];

    to this




    if(isset($_POST['btnsearch']))
        {
        $searchq =trim(strip_tags( $_POST['search']));  
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE initial LIKE '%$searchq%' OR lname    LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die ("could not search");
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);

    // you can also use empty($searchq)
        if(!strlen($searchq) >0 || $count==FALSE)
        {
        print whatever you want to print here
        }
```

and please stop using **mysql_query**

It was deprecated before it was deprecated.

Comment: it works but now .. when i type a wrong value in my textbox there's no message.. what i want is if the textbox is null or if i type something that is wrong ... my msg. "theres no result" will appear... sorry but im just new in php .. so i do need your help ... thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: **if(!strlen($searchq) >0 || $count==FALSE)** check this line...tell me if still you get any problem

Answer (score 1):

Check the search keyword instead of query like below

```
$searchq = trim($_POST['search']);
if(!empty($searchq)){
    // query 
}else {
    $output = 'There was no search results!';

}
```

Comment: What about blank space?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a js function which not allowed you to submit without input something in your search box.

and also you can handle this in php code that your submitting textbox value is empty of not.

Comment: You should write the suggestion as comment bro :)